# YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI error after upgrading to 13.09.57

Tags: youtube-api

My OS version is android 19.
I got below error when YouTube apk upgraded from `13.07.55` to `13.09.57`.
After I remove YouTube to factory version and upgrade to `13.09.57` again, this issue does not happen.

```
    03-16 09:28:00.535 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay:adbk@4315c310 helper:Lazy@4315da58 view:null status: ....... {...}
    03-16 09:28:00.645 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: onInitializationSuccess wasRestored:false
    03-16 09:28:00.645 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: loadYoutube:true
    03-16 09:28:00.645 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: loadYoutube :PLelK7aEMtfK28dT6AqmCJBClOBegKt-6N isEnd:false
    03-16 09:28:00.655 556-677/? I/MediaFocusControl:   Remote Control   registerMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{419a2038: PendingIntentRecord{41e96490 com.google.android.youtube broadcastIntent}}
    03-16 09:28:00.655 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/MainActivity: onStop
    03-16 09:28:00.655 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/MainActivity: onStop Playing:true
    03-16 09:28:00.655 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/MainActivity: onStop isGotoAnotherActivity:true
    03-16 09:28:00.735 1854-4423/? D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.adshield.ChimeraAdShieldCreatorImpl
    03-16 09:28:00.735 134-542/? W/AudioFlinger: write blocked for 327 msecs, 2856 delayed writes, thread 0xb3676008
    03-16 09:28:00.735 134-543/? W/AudioFlinger: write blocked for 328 msecs, 2854 delayed writes, thread 0xb34f4008
    03-16 09:28:00.755 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: ####################youtube video onStopped
    03-16 09:28:00.755 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: m_youtube_player onLoading
    03-16 09:28:00.875 1854-4423/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Failed to construct CronetEngine. Using fallback Java implementation.
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Disk cache storage path already in use
                                                                  at org.chromium.net.impl.CronetUrlRequestContext.(SourceFile:28)
                                                                  at ania.a(SourceFile:9)
                                                                  at andg.a(SourceFile:8)
                                                                  at trp.a(SourceFile:38)
                                                                  at trr.get(SourceFile:18)
                                                                  at ampq.get(SourceFile:10)
                                                                  at kna.K(SourceFile:157)
                                                                  at kmk.get(SourceFile:6)
                                                                  at ampq.get(SourceFile:10)
                                                                  at trx.a(SourceFile:52)
                                                                  at aaoh.b(SourceFile:21)
                                                                  at aanw.a(SourceFile:18)
                                                                  at aali.c(SourceFile:48)
                                                                  at aali.a(SourceFile:70)
                                                                  at vyq.e(SourceFile:39)
                                                                  at tss.c(SourceFile:81)
                                                                  at tss.run(SourceFile:37)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                  at tke.run(SourceFile:24)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    03-16 09:28:01.225 4269-4345/com.novosync.novods I/UTP Server RC: QUERY_STATUS m_is_downloading:false
    03-16 09:28:01.515 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/AutoUpdateAsyncTask: [onPreExecute] enabled = false
    03-16 09:28:02.245 4269-4345/com.novosync.novods I/UTP Server RC: QUERY_STATUS m_is_downloading:false
    03-16 09:28:02.775 1854-1854/? W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: ECatcher disabled: level: ERROR, category: player, message: currentWatchNextResponse was null when it shouldn't be
                                                              java.lang.Exception
                                                                  at aams.a(SourceFile:3)
                                                                  at adfk.a(SourceFile:152)
                                                                  at adfk.d(SourceFile:112)
                                                                  at adfk.a(SourceFile:96)
                                                                  at adfl.a(SourceFile:36)
                                                                  at adfy.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-16 09:28:02.815 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: m_youtube_player onLoaded
    03-16 09:28:02.815 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: m_youtube_player onVideoStarted
    03-16 09:28:02.865 4269-4269/com.novosync.novods I/PageActivity: m_youtube_player onError:INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Comment: Please share your code, not only an error log. Please also format your code and log for better readability.

Comment: This is an extremely strange issue because I'm using the same code in two of my apps and it stopped working yesterday only in one of them! (before updating to 13.09.57, I did it now).

Comment: The following methods are being called: onInitializationSuccess
onStopped()
onLoading()
onLoaded()
onVideoStarted() 
onSeekTo() (called in code)
onBuffering(true)
Next is the error mentioned in your code, onBuffering(false) and on Paused()

Comment: I also got same error! please let us know if you find a way to fix it

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to why this error appear?